# Python: overriding __nonzero__ for instances in multiple condition statements

Tags: python, exception, undefined

I have an attribute `undefined_atr` which is an instance of the class `Undefined` shown below.

```
class Undefined(object):
    def __nonzero__(self):
       raise ValueError()
```

`undefined_atr = Undefined()`

The idea is to use this class instead of `None` to ensure that Python will raise an exception for the following statement instead of setting `result` to `True`, which it would do if `undefined_atr` was `None`.

```
result = not undefined_atr
```

This all works fine, but if I have a multi condition statement like the one below, an exception is not raised unless `undefined_atr` is the first operand.

```
result = True and undefined_atr # Does not raise exception
result = undefined_atr and True # Raises exception
```

Any ideas why Python doesn't use my version of `__nonzero__` in the first of these cases and if it's possible to force it to?

Note that the following does produce the exception, so for some reason the 'not' causes the overridden `__nonzero__` to be called.

```
result = True and not undefined_atr # Raises exception
```

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? The statement `True and not undefined_atr` results in `ValueError` for me on Python 2.7.10.

Comment: Presumably either OP is using `or` or OP means `False` instead of `True`.  Either way, it's [short circuit logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and can't be trivially disabled.

Comment: @ jeremija Hmmm... I'm using Python 2.7 too. You're right it does work the way I wanted too. I think there's a problem  with my actual project code (which I can't show on here) then. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @jeremija and Kevin Corrected the logic in the last example. It seems strange that it works one way round, but not the other.

Comment: @ManInBlue: Read Kevin's link on short circuit logic. When the logic is short-circuited in a compound boolean expression, it's not even loading your `undefined_atr`, let alone checking it for "truthiness".

Comment: Totally off-topic: If you want this code to work on both Py2 and Py3, add `__bool__ = __nonzero__` after defining `__nonzero__`. That will ensure the correct name is defined for whichever version of Python you use this on.

Comment: This feels like an "XY problem", please explain your intent with the `Undefined` class to force raising an exception on undefined attributes. My response is "Why don't you just leave undefined attributes totally undefined, i.e. never declare them at all, then you force a `NameError`(/`AttributeError`) when you try to reference them?" How does your `Undefined` class add anything at all?

Comment: @ManInBlue `True and undefined_attr` will never raise an exception because once the interpreter notices the part before `and` operator is `True`, it will never invoke the `__nonzero__()` method. On the other hand, in the case of `undefined_attr and True`, the `__nonzero__()` method is executed and thus the `ValueError` is thrown. @Kevin is right, you should read more about short circuit logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x and y` doesn't actually try to interpret `y` as a boolean. It's equivalent to

```
y if x else x
```

except that `x` is only evaluated once. Similarly, `x or y` is equivalent to

```
x if x else y
```

No value of `undefined_atr` will cause `True and undefined_atr` to raise an error.

Comment: Thanks for explaining; it makes sense now why x and not y was working as expected. So this means that Python's logical and is non-commutative?

Comment: @ManInBlue: Most languages' logical and operations are already non-commutative due to short-circuiting, but yeah, this is extra non-commutative.